# java selenium solution required for load page with ajax and submit form

Tags: java, ajax, selenium

Java - My target is to get complete web page source(html) fill form and submit.

These days web pages are very complex to read b/c they do not get load in one page request call, they execute scripts on page load to fetch data from server and inject in page itself.

Thats where i am having problem, page i am trying to work with having multiple ajax calls to load forms inside and i have to fill the form and submit it pragmatically to get the result.

I tried "selenium" and used HtmlUnitDriver to do all things in background but selenium is failing on Javascript execution after enabling the js.

I want to get all page in one call regardless of if it have ajax calls to load different sections of the page.

One solution i am guessing may be if there is any thing like running server and requesting with url to get page which also maintain the session to submit form or some thing like that.

please feel free to share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make similar thing in my job. I use HtmlUnit (because it does not rendering -> faster than selenium). A little problematic is to wait when Ajax loading is finished. I poll and look if expected parts of HTML-code are present in the page, which are inserted by ajax.
When I am sure that all needed parts are loaded by ajax, I fill the form and submit it.

Comment: the page i am trying to access it have facebook script thats why i am getting exception as follows Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Access to restricted URI denied (script in http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com/cheapoair&layout=button_count&show_faces=true&width=80&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=21 from (109, 78) to (109, 2233)#109)

Comment: do you need the javascript of third (at different domain than the web-site) parties to be executed?

Comment: Maybe you can simply ignore `ScriptException`s. `webClient().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);`